# how to make shopping cart using django

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models, relationship

I'm making a shopping cart with two class models, one user can order multiple products
I used the many-to-many relationships. but I'm facing some issues like if two users has order same product then the last user's selected qty will show in both user's order. and many times it shows all orders in the user's cart by default.
please tell the correct way to write these models. So each users cart can't affect others

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.Productname

class Cart(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, default=None, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to have more than 1 order for a given product.
So the OrderItem should have a FK to the Product not onetoone.

I don't think you would have the same order in multiple carts, so you probably want a single FK from the OrderItem to the user's cart.